# cannot find symbol class ParseCrashReporting

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to resolve this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class **ParseCrashReporting**
```

I am using :

```
import com.parse.ParseCrashReporting;
```

I have searched on the stackoverflow and Google but can't find any solution. I am using Parse SDK as Parse-1.8.2.jar file in libs folder and then in gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: Have you also included ParseCrashReporting-1.x.x.jar in lib folder ?

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble in the past with (1) updating android studio and (2) updating to make sure I have most recent parse SDK to work with the most recent android studio build. One thing that seems to get ALL of the parse components working is downloading their most recent ParseStarterProject. This seems tedious and, should be, unnecessary, but a project rebuild with most recent resources may save you from future headaches. Hope it works out man!

Comment: @aquaballin_dc: Yes after adding jar file I have to do project rebuild...